# HTTP requests from Illustrator script?

Tags: http, scripting, adobe-illustrator

I know this question was asked several years ago ([How to make HTTP requests from Illustrator script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125404/how-to-make-http-requests-from-illustrator-script)), but the solutions don't seem to be working all these years later.

Has anyone successfully made HTTP requests from an Illustrator script in recent history?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably it can be done nowadays via CEP:

https://awesomeopensource.com/project/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides

https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides/tree/master/Network%20requests%20and%20responses%20with%20Fetch

But I haven't tried it. Because I'm too old and too lazy.

Comment: This looks like what I need. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.